# Can flash website work without flashplayer?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript, web

I just create an interactive flash website and it doesnt work without flash player. Is there a code to make my website work well on any browser and without flashplayer?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news, if you want to run flash animation in a web page, the browser should have FlashPlayer installed and enabled.

But if it's not in a webpage, you have the possibility to convert your Flash animation in an application with Adobe AIR for desktop and mobile. 
http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html

With the last Flash IDE (Animate CC), you can export your Flash animation in HTML5, to be compatible with a browser that not have Flash Player. But not support all Flash functionalities. 
https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html

Comment: well that's really some bad news, but thanks for your help :)